# How to disable select option in Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Good day! I am new in Vuejs. Please help me.
I want to disable the select option after I select and set the select to default value.
for example

```
<select name="recipient" @change="changeFunc($event)">
    <option>--Select--</option>
    <option v-for="recipient in recipients" :key="recipient.id" :value="recipient.id" :disabled="recipient.disabled">{{ recipient.name }}</option>
</select>
```

```
export default {
   data: function() {
       return {
           recipients: [
              {'id':3, 'name':'aaa'},
              {'id':5, 'name':'bbb'},
              {'id':8, 'name':'ccc'}
           ],
       }
   },
   method: {
       changeFunc(e) {
          //TODO disable the select value and set to default value
       }
   }
}
```

Please help how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried adding a disabled attribute to it

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
<select name="recipient" v-model="selected" @change="changeFunc($event)">
  <option>--Select--</option>
  <option v-for="recipient in recipients" :key="recipient.id" :value="recipient.id" :disabled="recipient.disabled">{{ recipient.name }}</option>

</select>


export default {
data: function() {
   return {
       selected: {},
       recipients: [
          {'id':3, 'name':'aaa', 'disabled': false},
          {'id':5, 'name':'bbb', 'disabled': false},
          {'id':8, 'name':'ccc', 'disabled': false}
       ],
   }
},
method: {
   changeFunc(e) {
      const index = this.recepients.findIndex((el) =>{
        if(el.id == this.selected){
           return true;
        }
     });
     
     if(index){
       this.recepeints[index].disabled = true;
       this.selected = "";
     }
   }
 }
}
```

The changeFunc() find index of selected value and set disabled to true and reset selected value

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a simple approach by iterating the input array on option change.

```
this.recipients.forEach(obj => {
    obj['disabled'] = (obj.id === this.recipient)
});
```

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    recipient: '',
    recipients: [
      {'id':3, 'name':'aaa'},
      {'id':5, 'name':'bbb'},
      {'id':8, 'name':'ccc'}
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    changeFunc() {
      this.recipients.forEach(obj => {
        obj['disabled'] = (obj.id === this.recipient)
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="recipient" @change="changeFunc">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option v-for="recipient in recipients" :key="recipient.id" :value="recipient.id" :disabled="recipient.disabled">{{ recipient.name }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: @Mobie Please do accept the answer if it helps. So that it will be helpful for other developers as well.